# How to define guards for different types of input than expected?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to transform an input list into a palindrome. For instance:

```
Input: [1,2,3]
Output: [1,2,3,3,2,1]
```

Basically I need to add a reversed list. My problem lies in the following:

```
palindrize::[a]->[a]
palindrize list | null list = []
palindrize (x:xs)=(x:xs)++revert(x:xs) where
                  revert list | null list =[] 
                  revert (x:xs)= (revert xs):(x:[])   ---Here
```

How can I create a guard or a condition to when there is only one element create a list out of it (applying the `(myelement:[])`)? I would need somehow to say: `revert` can get a list or an element, if it's an element apply `(element:[])` on it.

Comment: Why not =) `(<>) <*> reverse $ [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you make things too complex. First of all, Haskell has already a [**`reverse :: [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) that reverses the list, so we can make it:

```
palindrize :: [a] -> [a]
palindrize l = l ++ reverse l
```

Furthermore there is no need to use a guard here. We can perform pattern matching: this is safer since the compiler can then guarantee us that all patterns are covered. So we can write it like:

```
revert :: [a] -> [a]
revert [] = []
revert (x:xs) = (revert xs):(x:[])  -- error!
```

But this will result in a type error. Indeed, the `(:)` constructor has type `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, but `revert xs` will result in type `[a]`. In situations like that one, it is best to use an *accumulator*: a parameter that we initialize for instance with the empty list, and then each recursive call update and at the end of the recursive process return. For example:

```
revert :: [a] -> [a]
revert = go []
    where go xs [] = xs
          go xs (x:ys) = go (x:xs) ys
```

Comment: I wanted to create my own revert.And i know you can't  add a list to a single element .that is why i tried to first check if there's a single element (not in a list ! ) and concatenate it with the empty list,and then perform mylist++(listified single element)

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: yes, this would also work. But the disadvantage is that `(++)` runs in O(n) so that would make it a O(n^2) algorithm. By using an accumulator, we keep the reverse linear time.

Comment: Just for learning reasons  in my case in the revert function how can i define the base case behaviour  if (element is single) then  apply :[] on it) ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: you can write a single element as `revert [x] = [x]`, since the pattern is a singleton list `[x]` (with single element `x`), and the result is thus again a singleton list `[x]`.

Comment: Oh you are right.So when i define the pattern it won't even touch the other patterns (call the inner function.) Thanks !

Comment: There's a typo in the type of `(:)`: the first `->` should be replaced with `::`. I can't edit because that's too short an edit for SO. I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can not write `list : element`, nor `list : (element : [])` since types would not match: whatever is found at the left side of `:` must have the same type as the elements of the list found at the right side.

You can, however, append two lists using `++`, like `list ++ (element : [])` or `list ++ [element]`.

Second, to pattern match against a single element list, you can use

```
foo [] = ... -- empty list case
foo [x] = ... -- single element list case
foo (x1:x2:rest) = ... -- two elements or more case
```

If you prefer, the single element case can also be written `foo (x:[]) = ...`.

Note that `foo [] = ...` is equivalent to `foo list | null list = ...`, but simpler. If possible, forget guards: they should only be used when pattern matching is not enough.

Comment: So when my tail recursion reaches a single element it's type is not a but [a].

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: the type of the single element (here `x`) is `a`, the type of the list `[x]` is thus `[a]`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian In the single element case, the type of `[x]` is `[a]` (as any function argument), the type of `x` is `a`.

Comment: Well when you perform tail recursion in a function like : func (x:xs)=if null (x:xs) then [] else x + func(xs)   -- in the else case ,the x is of type a not type [a]

Comment: I wanted to put a condition in the if case something like : if (x is one element of type a -> apply x:[]) else ....

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian The type is correct. However, note that `null (x:xs)` is always false -- that list is never null! Also, that is not tail recursion.

Comment: Well in vscode-haskelly the linter tells me in the base case of a function like the one described above instead of using if mylist==[] then... to use if null mylist.Also what is this called if not tail recursion?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian It's just recursion. A tail recursive function calls itself and the function returned by the recursive call is the return value itself. E.g. `f x = if ... then f (x+1) else f (x-1)` is tail recursion, `... else 2*f(x-1)` is not because after the call we perform `2*`. And indeed `xs==[]` is worse than `null xs`, which is worse than pattern matching against `[]` directly as done above in the answer.